# Qubes OS:install kernel-headers/kernel-devel on sys-net without internet connection

Tags: linux, packages

I need to build a wifi driver, but to build it I need the kernel header files installed on my net-vm (fedora) on Qubes OS and because it is my wifi driver I can't access the Internet.Now my question is how to install the header files without internet?
kernelversion:

```
4.1.13-9.pvops.qubes.x86_64
```

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.I used the yum.repos.d directory to get the correct URL to get a compatible rpm package.